# UITableView with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, sprite-kit

How can I implement a UITableView with spriteKit? I know that I have create the tableView as an outlet in the ViewController file, but how can I access this tableView from my gameScene so I can change the position, size, cell content etc.

I have so far not been able to find any useful instructions or documentation regarding this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use your UITableView (that was created in a storyboard, you said outlet so I am guessing that is where you created it) within your scene you will need to do a few things.

First create a variable for your table view in your scene. My swift is rusty, but if it was Objective-C it would be a matter of creating a property in the YourScene.h file.

Now when you instantiate your scene you can set the table view you have an outlet for in your scene. Something like this...

```
scene.tableView = tableView
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Next thing in your scene you would want to implement `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` That way in your `didMoveToView` in your scene you can do this...

```
tableView?.delegate = self;
tableView?.dataSource = self;
```

Now in your scene you would have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

This should allow you to do anything you would do with a tableView within your scene code.

Just remember a UITableView is part of UIKit and will likely be sitting on top of your SKView (added as a child). Positioning and size will be in the UIKit coordinate system.

Hopefully that makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this is making more sense to me. Could you just explain this part a little further please: `scene.tableView = tableView` and
`skView.presentScene(scene)` what is the `scene.tableView` part? Is that supposed to be the property I created?

Comment: @Reece55 that should be in your view controller. In your view controller you should see `skView.presentScene(scene)` already. The other part is just setting your table view that you should have an outlet in your view controller to a variable you have in your scene. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been a huge help. I've been working on this one for a very long time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the view in the didMoveToView

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    // your table code
    [view addSubview:myTable];
}
```

Using view of SKView being the key here.

If you are in another method which does not have the SKView view, you can do this:

```
-(void)myMethod {
    SKView* view = self.view;
    // your table code
    [view addSubview:myTable];
}
```